# How to query an ActiveRecord table using conditions based on another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models - Blog and BlogTag. Blog has_many :blog_tags and BlogTag belongs_to :blog:

blog.rb

```
has_many :blog_tags
```

blog_Tag.rb

```
belongs_to :blog
```

I want to query the database to select all blogs that have tags matching in the blog_tags table based on what a user enters in a form field. Something like this:

```
Blog.where(blog_tags contain [array of tags])
```

Is there a way to do this with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming BlogTag has a column `name`.

```
Blog.joins(:blog_tags).where(blog_tags: { name: [array of tags] }).uniq
```

This would still return Blogs, but only blogs with blog tags whose name is in the array.

Comment: And if the blog has multiple tags from that array... (hinting a potential pitfall in the answer)

Comment: Yeah, it'll return multiples... probably needs a uniq

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this is by passing a `BlogTag` relation into a `Blog` scope.

```
Blog.where(id: BlogTag.where(name: tags).select(:blog_id))
```

So instead of a `JOIN`, ActiveRecord will construct a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE id IN (
  SELECT blog_id FROM blog_tags WHERE name IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')
)
```